# React native linkedin login is redirecting to url

Tags: android, react-native

i am implementing linked in login for my react native application.The package which i am using is `react-native-linkedin`.
But this is working fine i means this opens the webview modal and allows  user to enter there sign in credentials but the main problem is that after sign it is not firing any callback and it is opening the redirect url specified.
Here is the code for linkedin

```
 <View style={styles.container}>

           <LinkedInModal
             clientID="81b255y87agz"

             redirectUri="http://google.com"

             onSuccess={(token) => {
              console.log("getting token",token);
              ToastAndroid.show(token["access_token"].toString(),ToastAndroid.SHORT)
               }}


               onSignIn={(token) => {

                ToastAndroid.show(token["access_token"].toString(),ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                 }}

             onError={(error)=>{


              ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(error),ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                }}
           />

         </View>
```

None of these callbacks are called and after sign in it is opening google.com .How can i stop this ? Help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Callback to get the token:

```
         <LinkedInModal
                        clientID={CONSTANTS.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID}
                        clientSecret={CONSTANTS.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET}
                        redirectUri="http://usamamoin.com/auth"
                        onSuccess={token => this.authenticateLinkedin(token)}
                    />
```

After that you can get profile details from

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

To get Email:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Comment: i have same code but why it is opening redirect uri instead of calling onSuccess method

Comment: Have you entered the same redirect url in the linkedin app?

Comment: yes...if i change redirect url it in react native code then it gives errror that redirect uri doesn't match

Comment: Hello i am using api for getting the profile details and it is giving me error that not enough permission to access GET / me